# Aptana PHP showing a syntax error on member value assignment

Tags: php, aptana, syntax-error, variable-assignment

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious here.

I am getting a syntax error for the code:

```
private $crlf = chr(13).chr(10);
```

It's complaining about unfinished class declarations and an unexpected `(`.

I assumed this may be due to it being a function call (do the return values resolve at compile time?) after reading through http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php.

But then I notice in example 1 on the above link the line

```
public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
```

Which still generates syntax errors for because if the bracket.

Is this just an Aptana issue? If so, can anyone point me toward modifying the error highlighting in Aptana v2.0.5?

Comment: There's a comment in the code example that states that all of those property declarations are invalid, except for `$var8` which works in PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a mistake by Aptana Studio; it's really a syntax error in PHP. Indeed, when declaring class members, you can't assign the return values of function or method calls to them, because function calls cannot be evaluated at compile time.

If you try to run your script in a browser, PHP will spit a parse error as well.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: I'm just going to assume it was an accident, and bump it so whoever it was can fix their vote... I have better things to think about on my birthday than a quiet downvote :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me! My apologies for skim reading and Happy Birthday